# Processing user input during execution

Tags: powershell

How can I make it that my script listens for user input while it is running and performing background taks.
"Read-host" does not do what I want because it shows a prompt and it waits for user input.
I don't want to wait as user input is not mandatory. It is more that during script execution (script runs long time looping) I want to change certain parameters without stopping the script.

So for example when I press 4 on the keyboard the script should pick it up while running and set a specific variable to "4" and keeps processing with the variable set to this value.

It sounds like the solution would be to use some kind of "listener" that sits in the background and listens to keyboard strokes, but I don't know if this can be done with Powershell.

Edit: I edit the post for some clarification. It is not real code but shows the structure. There is an ever lasting loop that creates a number of background tasks. If the number falls below a limit, new background tasks get created.
What I want is to be able to change $limit by typing in a new value, while the while loop keeps running. The loop must continue running and not wait for input as the input is completely optionally.

```
$limit = SOME_VALUE
while($condition)
    { 
      if ($total_number_of_background_tasks < $limit) {
          create new background task }
    }
Continue to do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, it waits for a key press and stores key press into a variable:

```
while($true){
  $key = [Console]::ReadKey().Key.ToString()
}
```

The $key is overwritten each time, so to append key presses to it:

```
$key = ""
while($true){
  $key += [Console]::Readkey().Key.Tostring()
}
```

To store keys as array:

```
$key = @()
# Like upper one
```

Array can be retrieved like $key[index starting from 0]

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is, it should not wait for a key press. Waiting for key press means pausing the main thread which halts the creation of new background tasks.

Comment: Using jobs will be very useful in this purpose. Jobs run asynchronously in background, and does not interrupt the execution of other commands. You run a job before starting the while loop, it will be executing and you can get results letter. And the keypress listener will go on its own pace. Open powershell and type `Get-Help about_jobs` to know in detail.